# Websockets using "SockJS+spring websocket" error when trying to connect the websocket (404: path of STOMP endpoint not found)

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux, sockjs

**In my web application, i tried to connect to the websocket using SockJS, but an error message is returned (404 path "/stomp/info" not found) :**

**This question is asked numerous times, but i fail to find an answer for my situation**
**Could anyone help me to find the solution ?**

### Here is my code

**- Server side based on spring web flux, spring security (JWT) [spring boot version: 2.1.2RELEASE]**

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/prob");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/prob");
    }

    @Override

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/stomp")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                //.setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);

        messageConverters.add(converter);

        return false;
    }
}
```

**CORSFilter.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CORSFilter implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Max-Age",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Method")
                .maxAge(3600)
                .allowCredentials(false);
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .cors().and().headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/login","/stomp","/stomp/**","/stomp/info","/stomp/info/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().build();
    }
}
```

**- Client side based on Angular (stompjs + sockjs-client)**

```
socketConnect() {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8081/stomp');
    this.stompClient = StompJS.Stomp.over(socket);

    const _this = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
      _this.stompClient.subscribe('/prob/' + _this.id + '/newcomment', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

### UPDATE

**I changed the configuration of the CORS Filter :**

```
@Configuration
public class CORSFilter{
    @Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter(){
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",config);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
```

**But i still having an other error :**

> GET http://localhost:8081/stomp/info?t=1602859336795 404 (not found)

**Here is the logs of initialization of websocket in the server side :**

```
2020-10-16 15:41:14.712  INFO 13060 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2020-10-16 15:41:14.712  INFO 13060 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [DefaultSubscriptionRegistry[cache[0 destination(s)], registry[0 sessions]]]]
2020-10-16 15:41:14.714  INFO 13060 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
...
2020-10-16 15:42:13.750  INFO 13060 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Comment: im guessing here but `.cors().and().headers().frameOptions().disable().and()` wont work, try `.cors().disable().and().....` or instead try remove your own cors configuration and use the spring security cors filter and configure it according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors

Comment: @ThomasAndolf i tried your solution but still not working

Comment: Please update your question with all things you have tried, all your DEBUG logs, and have you even debugged the Spring CORS filters?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf **I updated the question by adding the log,** thank you for your comments :)

Comment: you have not posted the DEBUG logs, or the DEBUG logs for spring security

Comment: I tried to enable debug logs for spring security but nothing is showing because I used the reactive version of spring (spring web flux)

Comment: If you need help you need to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf i resolved the problem of the CORS policy, but i still having an other error (404, path "/stomp/info" not found), i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally i found the issue,
the problem is i used websocket configuration for spring-mvc and not spring-webflux, i found a good tuto to implement websocket in reactive context with spring-webflux : [enter link description here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/24/reactive-apis-with-spring-webflux)

Comment: Can you expand on this? I have the same issue, seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932577/how-do-i-connect-my-sockjs-client-to-my-spring-boot-websocket-endpoint